# mongoimport - $addToSet/$push with upsert?

Tags: mongodb, upsert

Is it possible to write JSON that will cause `mongoimport` to [append to existing arrays](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet) during an [upsert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aImportingwith%7B%7Bupsert%7D%7D)? (mongodb 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, as of now (9/26/11) this is not possible.  Users with this problem are encouraged to write their own import script.